# How to select a specific part of the element in XPath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am working on scraping specific data of a website using scrapy and by copying the Xpath. I have this element, however I'd like to select only one part of the element.

The element/argument is:

```
{"cat42":"0","taal":"nl","loggedin":"false","cat1":"noordbrabant","cat2":"eindhoven","cat3":"5655jb","cat4":"83","cat6":"949949","cat7":"woonhuis","cat8":"6","cat9":"211","cat10":"c","cat11":"62584","cat12":"villa","cat13":"bestaandebouw","cat24":"0","cat26":"vbo","cat28":"1","cat29":"1978","cat30":"900000","cat33":"koop","cat34":"verkocht","cat35":"88909230","cat36":"0","cat38":"gemeenteeindhoven","cat39":"ooievaarsnest","cat43":"0","cat44":"0","postcode":"5655jb","plaats":"eindhoven","provincie":"noordbrabant","huisnummer":"83","woonoppervlakte":"211","vraagprijs":"949949","aantalkamers":"6","soortobject":"woonhuis","energieklasse":"c","hoofdaanbieder":"62584","bouwvorm":"bestaandebouw","soortwoning":"villa","bedrijfsruimte":"false","branchevereniging":"vbo","dakterras":"false","tuin":"true","balkon":"false","soortaanbieding":"koop","tinyid":"88909230","vraagprijsrange":"900000","bouwjaar":"1978","openhuis":"false","gemeente":"eindhoven","buurt":"ooievaarsnest","monumentalestatus":"false","rijksmonument":"false","soortaanbod":"koop","energiezuinig":"false","kluswoning":"false","adgroup":"b","status":"verkocht","environment":"production"}
```

I'd like to select only `"tuin":"true"` using xpath. I have tried: `response.xpath('//tuin[@id="content"]/script[1]/text()').extract()` but it gives me '[]' as a result.

So how can I select only the part that I want?

Comment: @Prophet how can I do that?

Comment: Generally, when you asking a question and getting answered and that question helped you you should accept the answer. 1) To indicate the problem is resolved 2) To say "Thanks" to a person who helped you - this will give points both to you and to him.

Comment: could you please add url or html part?
please explain in brief it's shows json string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Prophet the problem is that I cannot find the tick that allows me to indicate the problem is resolved. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: @Aniruddhsinh the url is https://www.funda.nl/koop/verkocht/eindhoven/huis-88909230-ulenpas-83/

Comment: @Aniruddhsinh the json string is <script type="application/ld+json" data-advertisement-targeting="">

Answer (score 0):

let me know if i am wrong

by help of xpath you can only select html tags

according to your requirement you have to check string content in specific element

you can't select script text by xpath directly you have add some logic for retrieve exact element.

here is sample code for extract

```
import scrapy


class FundaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'funda'
    allowed_domains = ['funda.nl']
    start_urls = ['https://www.funda.nl/koop/verkocht/eindhoven/huis-88909230-ulenpas-83/']

    def parse(self, response):
        tuin_json_texts = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').getall()
        for single_json in tuin_json_texts:
            expected_text = '\"tuin\":\"true\"'
            if expected_text in single_json:
                print(single_json.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with scrapy shell:

```py
scrapy shell https://www.funda.nl/koop/verkocht/eindhoven/huis-88909230-ulenpas-83/

In [1]: response.xpath('//main[@id="content"]/script//text()').get().strip()
Out[1]: '{"cat42":"0","taal":"nl","loggedin":"false","cat1":"noordbrabant","cat2":"eindhoven","cat3":"5655jb","cat4":"83","cat6":"949949","cat7":"woonhuis","cat8":"6","cat9":"211","cat10":"c","cat11":"62584","cat12":"villa","cat13":"bestaandebouw","cat24":"0","cat26":"vbo","cat28":"1","cat29":"1978","cat30":"900000","cat33":"koop","cat34":"verkocht","cat35":"88909230","cat36":"0","cat38":"gemeenteeindhoven","cat39":"ooievaarsnest","cat43":"0","cat44":"0","postcode":"5655jb","plaats":"eindhoven","provincie":"noordbrabant","huisnummer":"83","woonoppervlakte":"211","vraagprijs":"949949","aantalkamers":"6","soortobject":"woonhuis","energieklasse":"c","hoofdaanbieder":"62584","bouwvorm":"bestaandebouw","soortwoning":"villa","bedrijfsruimte":"false","branchevereniging":"vbo","dakterras":"false","tuin":"true","balkon":"false","soortaanbieding":"koop","tinyid":"88909230","vraagprijsrange":"900000","bouwjaar":"1978","openhuis":"false","gemeente":"eindhoven","buurt":"ooievaarsnest","monumentalestatus":"false","rijksmonument":"false","soortaanbod":"koop","energiezuinig":"false","kluswoning":"false","adgroup":"b","status":"verkocht","environment":"production"}'
```

Now you can get values with their keys by using json:

```py
In [2]: data = response.xpath('//main[@id="content"]/script//text()').get().strip()

In [3]: import json

In [4]: json_data = json.loads(data)

In [5]: json_data['tuin']
Out[5]: 'true'

In [6]: json_data['environment']
Out[6]: 'production'

In [7]: json_data['woonoppervlakte']
Out[7]: '211'
```